# how to import function from sub directory in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, module, subdirectory

I have  a project with below structure:

[image]

TestDir.**init**.py contains:

```
from . import TestSubDirFile
```

TestDir.TestSubDirFile.py contains:

```
class TestSubDirFile:
def test_funct(self):
    print("Hello World")
```

ds_scheduler.py contains:

```
from TestDir import TestSubDirFile as tp

def test_job():
    testobj = tp.test_funct()
    print("Test job executed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     test_job()
```

Getting Output as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python_Projects/Test/com/xyz/ds/ds_schedular.py", line 9, in <module>
test_job()
 File "C:/Python_Projects/Test/com/xyz/ds/ds_schedular.py", line 5, in test_job
testobj = tp.test_funct()
AttributeError: module 'TestDir.TestSubDirFile' has no attribute 'test_funct'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your directory structure 
*ds_scheduler.py

TestDir -- Directory Name

- TestSubDirFile.py - Python filename*

Within **TestSubDirFile.py** file you have defined your class with name **TestSubDirFile**.

`from TestDir import TestSubDirFile as tp`

As per your above import statement you are only accessing till the py file.

To access test_func() method within class you need to follow below steps.

`tsdf = tp.TestSubDirFile()
tsdf.test_funct()`

Hope this helps